# Javascript blocks selecting text: how to unblock?

Tags: browser, javascript

Is a way to unblock blocked (by JS) text selecting on some website ? I'm using Chrome. **UPDATE**: Blocking JS code is in page source (...  blocking code here  ...)

Comment: Open the page source and copy it from there

Answer (score 2):

I've found solution in Chrome -> my own [extension](https://github.com/marioosh-net/chrome-plugins/tree/master/textcopy_unblocker).

**contentscript.js:**

```
document.oncopy= function(){
    return true;
} 

document.ondragstart= function(){
    return true;
}

document.onselectstart= function(){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I can't load your extension: "Failed to load extension
File
~/Proj/temp/unlock/chrome-plugins-master/textcopy_unblocker/WebContent
Error
The 'manifest_version' key must be present and set to 2 (without quotes). See developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html for details.
Could not load manifest."               

Could this be made into a javascript snippet so it's possible to run from `Developer>JavaScript Console ⌥⌘J` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unblock it permanently, `Right click > View source` and copy the link to JavaScript file that's preventing the highlight. Add it to your adblock/blacklist extension, or even your hosts file ([list of locations for each OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system)) like this.

`127.0.0.1` http://incriminating.file/url.js

This will prevent the JavaScript file from being downloaded when you reload the page after clearing your cache. Bare in mind that your experience with the site might be handicapped with this method.

Comment: Blocking js is inside <body/>, not in separate file

Answer (score 0):

If your using Firefox, get the [noscript](http://noscript.net/) addon.